# Clearing cache programmaticaly in c

Tags: c, caching

Is there a way to clear/flush all memory cache cache data (current program cache or all cache data) from the system using only C language?

Comment: What "system"? Do you mean the CPU caches? Some OS-level cache? Some other cache?

Comment: Furthermore, what have you tried yourself? Do you have a [mcve] of your attempt to show us? What is the problem you have with your attempt? And please take some time to  read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: The abstract machine used in the C standards do not have CPU cache. Many systems that are programmed with C don't have CPU cache. Do you mean file cache or file system cache, which of course only apply to some targets?

Comment: sorry if my question is not clear, but this is what i have
" This can be done by generating a fresh series of memory accesses. The key here is to make sure thatall your accesses will touch all the cache blocks in your cache (so that you are guarantee to kick out anydata previously stored in the cache).
Hint: malloc a contiguous address that would cover an entire cache and touch all locations "
any idea of how can i do that ?

Comment: @mahdiiguadi There is no CPU cache from point of view of the abstract machine used by the C standard. You have to be much more precise. Which kind of Processor do you use? What kind of cache does it have? What do you exactly want (why)?

Comment: @12431234123412341234123
I have two functions
that use the same data and give the same output
but one is supposed to be faster because it optimises the cache memory access
so i'm mesuring the execution time for each function
and between execusions i need to flush data that already exists in the cash
so that there is nothing left from the previous function that can be exploited by the second function and lead to much shorter time

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Minimal reproducible examples are mostly for debugging questions and are not needed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C standard does not provide a completely portable way to flush cache. However, if you know the size of cache and it is a least-recently-used (LRU) or pseudo-LRU cache, you can do this:

```
// CacheSize is the number of bytes in cache.
// LineSize is the number of bytes in a cache line (use 1 if unknown).
volatile unsigned char *FlushBuffer = malloc(CacheSize);
if (!FlushBuffer)
    ComplainAndExit();

for (size_t i = 0; i < CacheSize; i += LineSize)
    FlushBuffer[i];
```

This will access every cache line in the allocated buffer, which will force every line that was in cache previously to be evicted. Because `volatile` is used, `FlushBuffer[i]` requires the compiler to generate an actual load instruction, not to optimize away the expression (if the compiler has any reasonable definition for what an access to memory is).

Do not free the memory until after measuring the functions. If you free it, the memory might be reused for other memory allocation calls, and then the functions would be using memory already in cache, which is not what you want. You should allocate the buffer once and execute the loop before each function to be measured, including the first function (so that all functions start with the same cache state).